# Eliminar imagen CLOUDINARY en Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

Soy nuevo en el manejo de APIS, siguiendo un ejemplo de internet logre subir imágenes a Cloudinary mediante peticiones HTTPS, y guardar la Ruta en una base de datos FIREBASE. para luego listarlos.
No encontré en la documentación un ejemplo claro para eliminar una imagen que se haya subido, o mi conocimiento es tan basto que no logro entender los ejemplos que estan en la Documentacion y pasarlo a codigo en Flutter.

Esta es la lista que recupero de Firebase, no se si necesite guardar alguna variable aparte del Url para poder eliminar la imagen alojada en Cloudinary, Cuando selecciono el dato. asi como se guarda el ID en Firebase para luego hacer la eliminacion.

[image: Esta es listado que recupero de firebase]

Este es el codigo que utilizo para subir la imagen a CLOUDINARY

```
Future<String> subirImagen(File imagen) async {
final url = Uri.parse(
    'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<mi_app>/image/upload?upload_preset=etcm9wft');
final mimeType = mime(imagen.path).split('/');

final imageUploadRequest = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', imagen.path,
    contentType: MediaType(mimeType[0], mimeType[1]));

imageUploadRequest.files.add(file);
final streamResponse=await imageUploadRequest.send();
final resp= await http.Response.fromStream(streamResponse);
if(resp.statusCode!=200&&resp.statusCode!=201){
  print("algo salio mal");
  print(resp.body);
  return null;
}
final respData= json.decode(resp.body);
print(respData);

return respData['secure_url'];

 }
```

Por favor cualquier tipo de ayuda me bastaria para investigar sobre el tema, estoy muy interesado en dominar y consumir todo tipo de APIS.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes borrar imagenes de Cloudinary desde la app de Flutter directamente, esto es por seguridad ya que cuando subes una foto desde flutter lo haces con un key publico.

Debes crear una Cloud Function en Firebase que se encargue de subir la imagen en Cloudinary desde Flutter, guardas el URL en firebase y cuando quieras borrar la imagen debes usar la CF con la url de la imagen.

Acá puedes encontrar mas información sobre el tema https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api